# How much f jQuery is used by Backbone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want to cut off jQuery from Backbone. How can I do that?

How can I provide only required jquery functionality to Backbone. Even if I write my own micro lib for that, how much of functinality to provide in that?

Comment: How much do you need? Backbone doesn't depend on jQuery. There is no inherent "required jQuery functionality".

Comment: @Juhana actually it kind of does if you want to use most of it, take a look at the part of the [docs](http://backbonejs.org/#) [@user3035961](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3035961/user3035961) quoted.

Comment: @Juhana, if soft dependencies are not included, Backbone only offers partial use of models and collections. Backbone.Router(), Backbone.View(), Backbone.History(), and Backbone.Sync() won't function properly.

Comment: Check this : [Backbone-native](https://github.com/inkling/backbone.native)

Answer (score 0):

*** Backbone's only hard dependency is Underscore.js ( >= 1.5.0). For RESTful persistence, history support via Backbone.Router and DOM manipulation with Backbone.View, include jQuery, and json2.js for older Internet Explorer support. (Mimics of the Underscore and jQuery APIs, such as Lo-Dash and Zepto, will also tend to work, with varying degrees of compatibility.)  ***

Backbone uses jquery for below backbone elements:
    Backbone.ajax uses $.ajax, 
    Backbone.delegateEvents,
    $(jQuery),
    $(el) - element)
If you want to use your microlib replace above elements